# Time Stamp from a button?

Tags: swift, button, time

Is there any way to record the time as a string when a button is pressed?
I have no idea where to start?

Comment: What part do you need help with? Break it down. Do you know how to handle a button press? Do you know how to get the current date? In what way to you want to record the time (update a label, something else)?

Comment: I know how to do the button press, I am just unsure of the overall concept of gathering time info. I have a start and stop button which operates a function and I am trying to record the date, time and the variables which are assigned to my function to be presented into a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the `IBAction` from that button like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short    
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    print(formatter.string(from: currentDateTime))
}
```